# List of packages in R for options pricing?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

What are the best packages in R or most comprehensive packages in R for option pricing and working with options?

Thanks!

Comment: @alexC you should post as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to browse the [Task View for empirical
finance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html), which lists many options-related packages.

As for concrete suggestions: I have worked a lot with [`RQuantLib`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RQuantLib)
in the past, and I have found it a reliable and stable package.

Perhaps I may also suggest [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF), which I maintain. It
provides implementations of a number of models
(Black/Scholes/Merton, Merton jump-diffusion, Heston, ...). It also implements the approach of [Bakshi/Madan (2000)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-405X(99)00050-1) for pricing based on the characteristic function. The implementation is essentially the one described in this paper on [Calibrating Option Pricing Models](https://ssrn.com/abstract=1566975).

Answer (score 6):

Besides those mentioned by Alex C., the package '*RND*' provides various tools for computing risk-neutral densities from option prices, and also provides some pricing functions for various models. [RND package on CRAN.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RND/RND.pdf) 
The package '*VarianceGamma*' provides tools for, inter alia, fitting a variance-gamma distribution to historical data complete with automatically generated histograms and QQ-plots.
[VarianceGamma package on CRAN.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VarianceGamma/VarianceGamma.pdf)

Comment: RND is an awesome tool, +1.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to investigate, among others, RQuantlib, derivmkts, fOptions, OptionPricing, M4FE. I have no detailed information about these, I have just seen or heard them mentioned (here or in other places).

Answer (score 1):

A newer package for option pricing, and for computation of Greeks and implied volatilities is the package [greeks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/greeks/index.html), which I have written.